# ace js find string in pre-defined line

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

how is it possible to find all the appearances of a string inside a pre-defined line?
e.g. I want to find the string ":

```
editor.findAll('"',{regExp:false});
editor.replace("");
```

This would replace all ". But how is it possible to say: I want to replace the " in line 6?

TY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ace allows to pass a range to find/findAll

```
Range = require("ace/range").Range;
editor.findAll(' ', {
    regExp: false, 
    range: new Range(row, 0, row, Number.MAX_VALUE)
});
```